# background color of h1 tag not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

```
import React from 'react'


export default function Home(){

return<div>

<h1 className="bg-dark text-white p-3">Home</h1>

 </div>
 }
```

I want to change the background color of h1 tag but not working in react and bootstrap is
imported  successfully and I have tested as well for button that works fine for me. Does some
give me  hint about it?

Comment: Have you properly imported bootstrap CSS? Does it work with other types of classes?

Answer (score 1):

The classes you have are for containers

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-dark text-white">
  <h1>Home</h1>
</div>
```

or use css

```css
.whiteonblack {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
  <h1 class="whiteonblack">Home</h1>
</div>
```